# Adding image to SVG circles

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I'm trying to add some background image to `SVG` nodes "circle".

I have read a lot of stackoverflow answer and everybody is saying that we need to add a  node into a  to define our image.

I tried this but my image is not displaying at all.

Here is a fiddle of my code: https://jsfiddle.net/baapu6wz/ .

What did I miss ?

```
<svg baseProfile="full" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="390" width="1629">
<g transform="translate(40,0)">
    <g>
        <line y2="149.3060251652327" x2="819.8567597731511" y1="222.22245513917517" x1="854.7332277213098" style="stroke: #999;" stroke-width="5"></line>
        <line y2="213.47136779636722" x2="768.9096407109324" y1="213.47136779636722" x1="768.9096407109324" style="stroke: #999;" stroke-width="5"></line>
        <line y2="213.47136779636722" x2="768.9096407109324" y1="149.3060251652327" x1="819.8567597731511" style="stroke: #999;" stroke-width="5"></line>
    </g>
    <g>
        <g transform="translate(854.7332277213098, 222.22245513917517)">
            <circle fill="url(#image1);" fillOpacity="0.5" r="16"></circle>
            <text x="20" dy="3">pagx</text>
        </g>
        <g transform="translate(768.9096407109324, 213.47136779636722)">
            <circle fill="url(#image1);" fillOpacity="0.5" r="10"></circle>
            <text x="20" dy="3">xzreds</text>
        </g>
        <g transform="translate(819.8567597731511, 149.3060251652327)">
            <circle fill="url(#image1);" fillOpacity="0.5" r="14"></circle>
            <text x="20" dy="3">jzkcwv</text>
        </g>
    </g>
</g>
<defs>
    <pattern width="16" height="16" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" y="0" x="0" id="image1">
        <image xlink:href="https://www.google.fr/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" height="16" width="16" y="0" x="0"></image>
    </pattern>
</defs>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo.

```
fill="url(#image1);"
```

should be

```
fill="url(#image1)"
```

Remove the semicolon.

https://jsfiddle.net/baapu6wz/1/

Comment: My bad, sometimes, we just need to take a break..  Thank you !!